# Highcharts/Highstocks: How to manually set the X-axis range

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

I am trying to set the x-axis range manually. So, my x-axis needs to be in the format of hours / minutes, and should be from 0 hours to 48 hours, increment each ticks by 15 minutes such that it is 0, 15 , 30, 45, 1:00, 1:15, 1:30, 1:45, 2:00..... to 48:00

I am unsure of how to do this, I am pulling data from an external Json file.

In my JavaScript, here is what I have

```
$(function () {

            $.getJSON('JsonFile.json', function (data) {

                var processedData = [];
                Highcharts.each(data, function (d) {
                    processedData.push(d.X);
                });

                // Create the chart
                $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
                    rangeSelector: {
                        selected: 1
                    },

                    title: {
                        text: 'X'
                    },

                    series: [{
                        data: processedData,
                        pointStart: Date.UTC(2010, 1, 1),
                        pointInterval: 1000 * 60 * 15 // Every 15 minute. 1000 miliseconds in 1 second, 60 seconds for 1 minute.
                    }],

                    xAxis: {
                         floor: 0,
                         ceiling: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 48,
                         type: 'datetime',
                         dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                         hour: '%H:%M'
                        }
                    }

                });
            });

        });
```

The way it is right now, it does not draw the graph, gives me an empty graph as shown
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJjzl.png)

Comment: Do you want to update the axis after creating the chart? what value type do you need?

Comment: I want it to have a fixed, initial axis when the page loads.
X-Axis should start from 0, increment by 15 minutes, all the way up to 48 hours so like, 0, 00:15, 00:30, 00:45, 01:00, 01:15..... 48:00. They should be in hours and minutes @AdiDarachi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `xAxis.labels.formatter`, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/cgoz4shr/1/

```
xAxis: {
  type: 'datetime',
  labels: {
    formatter: function(){
      var minutes = Highcharts.dateFormat('%M', this.value),
          days = parseInt(Highcharts.dateFormat('%d', this.value)) - 1,
          hours = days * 24 + parseInt(Highcharts.dateFormat('%H', this.value));

      return hours + ':' + minutes;
    }
  }
}
```

Reference to [`Highcharts.dateFormat`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Highcharts.dateFormat).

Of course, you can modify what is returned, for example, you can remove `hours` if `hours == 0` etc.

Comment: Fus, Thank you, your code works but on the x-axis, I get range of values from 24:00 to 216:00. Is there a way I can make it from 0:00 to 48:00? 

Also, could you please explain what var minutes and days line of codes are doing? I'm not following it, especially the var days line.

Comment: tried putting in 
'floor: 0,'
'ceiling: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 48,'

Comment: Maybe you have just to many points? Without live demo it is hard to say. Create jsFiddle (update mine for example) and we will think about this. That lines retrieves number of minutes and days from the the timestamp. I strongly advice to read the reference I posted.

Comment: I have updated your jsfiddle. There is indeed, too many data values (899 points) to be fit into 48 hours / 15, which is about 192 points compared to 899 data. Each point do not have to run for every 15th minute point cycle such that 899 data have to fit into 48 hours. So that results in each data points having to be ran for every 3.2 minutes. 
But it would be ideal to have the x-axis ticks labeled at every 15th minute.

Comment: Then I think you should change `pointInterval` according to the range between two points. Right now you have 15minutes set, if you have more points, calculate that distance and then set.

Answer (score 2):

### *Update 2*

I updated the fiddle to spread any number of datapoints over a 48 hour timespan. To have a tick label placed every 15 minutes you can add `tickInterval: 1000*60*15` to your xAxis options. However Highcharts will not render all labels if there isn't enough space available for them (even so it can be quite cluttered with this setting specified, see for yourself.)

See the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cgoz4shr/5/) for details.

---

Don't forget to check out the [HighCharts Documentation](http://www.highcharts.com/docs) and [API Reference](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.labels.formatter), They can be quite helpful :-)

Comment: Hi, I've attached an image to my question, the way it is right now - it does not draw the graph

Comment: @axchink can you please provide the structure of your JsonFile.json?

Comment: '{
    "Measure": ##,
    "Measure2":##,
  },
{
    "Measure": ##,
    "Measure2":##,
  },
{
    "Measure": ##,
    "Measure2":##,
  },
{
    "Measure": ##,
    "Measure2":##,
  },
{
    "Measure": ##,
    "Measure2":##,
  },
{
    "Measure": ##,
    "Measure2":##,
  }'

Comment: @axchink that doesn't really help, sorry. if the properties of your data objects are actually called 'measure1/2' then pushing d.X to processedData should not work. console.log() is your friend. Also, have you looked at my updated answer?

Comment: It doesn't load because `pointStart` is `Date.UTC(2010, 1, 1)` -> `1264982400000`, while `ceiling` is set to `1000 * 60 * 60 * 48` -> `172800000`. That means your max value on xAxis is lower than the first point in your series :)

Comment: @Arsylum Will take a look at your updated answer, an data names are actually "Measure1" and "Measure2"

Comment: @PawełFus Oh, thank you !! how did you convert 2010,1,1 to 1264982400000 ??  Is there a certain formula?

Comment: Magic. You know, `Date.UTC()` is method from Javascript, so I just called in in the JS console.

Comment: @PawełFus thank you, i'm about to leave comment on your answer you posted, but it won't let me tag by doing @

Comment: You don't have to target user if you write under it's own answer.

Comment: @axchink Please take a look at my second edit (cannot comment on the other answer)

Comment: I like it, could you please tell me why you put the (Math.sin) on the processed data though? my data consists of values from 0 to 75s, but with the sin, it is a pure sin-wave. Also, another thing is that Y-axis in this case is from -1 to 1 only.

Comment: There was no reason to it other than make the generated testdata look less boring than a straight line. Sorry if it was confusing.